# Как создать слайдер с произвольным содержимым на fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

Нужно реализовать подобный слайдер, как это можно сделать, используя API Fancybox?

В документации нашел только примеры с использованием изображений.

[image: Подобный слайдер нужно реализовать]